# How to generate a bar chart of occurrences per month from a pandas Series?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas Series which looks like this:

```
id
368683    2012-01-01 01:20:08
77642     2012-01-01 03:18:40
335652    2012-01-01 03:39:48

...
188283    2013-04-30 23:22:33
137637    2013-04-30 23:25:40
Name: created_time, Length: 223129
```

Now I want to create a bar chart, where I list the occurrences per month? What would be the pandas way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need histogram() of months. I think it could be done by creating another Series with months of given datetimes and then plot it:

```
m = s.apply(lambda x: x.month)
m.hist()
```

If you want to get your data in form like 'Jan 2011', ..., you can convert it like this

```
m = s.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y'))
```

Comment: Does month return just the month number? That will mess up if it's multi-year and he wants 2012-01 separate from 2013-01.

Comment: Yes, thats not what I wanted. I would like to have a histogram where I have "Jan 2011, Febr 2011,..." on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help so far. I ended up with the following code:

```
frame2 = DataFrame.from_csv("data/test.csv")
times2 = frame2['created_time']
m = times2.apply(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m'))
x=m.value_counts()
x=x.sort_index()
x.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot:
[image]